# If $f$ is smooth on a ball, does there exist $u$ smooth s.t. $\Delta u =f$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I knew from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575885/equation-delta-u-f) that if we have a function $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ then we can find a function $u\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ so that $\Delta u = f$.

My question: Assume that I have a function $f\in C^{\infty}(B)$. Here $B$ is the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Does there always exist $u\in C^{\infty}(B)$ so that $\Delta u = f$ on $B$?

Note that $f$ may behave badly near $\partial B$, for example $f \equiv d_{B}^{-k}$, where $d_{B}$ is the boundary distance function.

Comment: I’m not sure, but at first glance the construction of the thread that you link seems to carry over…

Comment: The answer is yes. Using some results from closed operators on Fréchet spaces and the Malgrange-Ehrenpreis theorem, it is possible to show that $\Delta \colon C^{\infty}(\Omega) \to C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is surjective for all open sets $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. In fact, this is not only true for the Laplace operator but for all elliptic differential operators $P(D) := \sum_{\lvert \alpha \rvert \leq m} a_{\alpha}D^{\alpha}$ with constant coefficients $a_{\alpha}$.

Comment: @Mike Thank you for your response. Your claim on the surjectivity of $\Delta$ seems to be a well-known result. Could you suggest a reference? Thank.

Comment: @Hana A classical source is Hoermander, "The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators II". Your problem is discussed in Chapter X. You can also find a quite different perspective in Wengenroth's "Derived Functors in Functional Analysis".